# Django why the pagination is not working?

Tags: django, pagination

Sorry because of the dumb question. I am reading a tutorial from book called build django 2 web application. and I get to the pagination topic but I can't get why it does not working even when I am copy-pasting carefully.

```
{% if is_paginated %}
<nav>
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item">
      <a href="{% url 'core:MovieList'%}?page=1" class="page-  link">First</a>
    </li>
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
      <li class="page-item">
        <a href="{% url 'core:MovieList' %}?page={{page_obj.previous_page_number}}" class="page-link">{{page_obj.previous_page_number}}</a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
    <li class="page-item active">
      <a href="{% url 'core:MovieList' %}?page={{page_obj.number}}" class="page-link">{{page_obj.number}}</a>
    </li>
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
      <li class="page-item">
        <a href="{% url 'core:MovieList' %}?page={{page_obj.next_page_number}}" class="page-link">{{page_obj.next_page_number}}</a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
    <li class="page-item">
      <a href="{% url 'core:MovieList' %}?page={{paginator.num_pages}}" class="page-link">Last</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
{% endif %}

#View
class MovieListView(ListView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'movie_list.html'
```

Comment: Can you show your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the `paginated_by` attribute in the view class, so the contents won't be paginated.

```
class MovieListView(ListView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'movie_list.html'
    paginate_by = 5
```

Comment: @daniel_roseman Do not need to use `queryset = Product.objects.all()` after set paginate value?

Comment: No, you only need to set the queryset if it's different from Model.objects.all().